# Создать цепочку из элементов массива

Tags: php

Есть два массива:

```
$correct = [                                                    
    ['first' => '148', 'last' => '002', 'num' => '1'],          
    ['first' => '155', 'last' => '156', 'num' => '2'],          
    ['first' => '975', 'last' => '148', 'num' => '1'],          
    ['first' => '156', 'last' => '157', 'num' => '2'],          
    ['first' => '002', 'last' => '155', 'num' => '2'],          
    ['first' => '051', 'last' => '978', 'num' => '2'],          
    ['first' => '157', 'last' => '051', 'num' => '2'],          
] ;
```

```
$incorrect = [
    ['first' => '156', 'last' => '157', 'num' => '2'],
    ['first' => '002', 'last' => '148', 'num' => '1'],
    ['first' => '155', 'last' => '156', 'num' => '2'],
    ['first' => '002', 'last' => '155', 'num' => '2'],
    ['first' => '051', 'last' => '978', 'num' => '2'],
    ['first' => '157', 'last' => '051', 'num' => '2'],
    ['first' => '148', 'last' => '975', 'num' => '1'],
] ;
```

С помощью `php` необходимо создать цепочку из элементов массива, так чтобы поле `last` текущей строки массива был равен поле `first` следующей строки массива, и так до конца массива.

При этом необходимо сортировать по убыванию по поле `num`.

И если есть разрыв цепочки то вывести его на экран, и дальше продолжить цепочку.

При выводе на экран нужно чтобы было:

```
// Если цепочка цельная [массив $correct]
first    last     num                                       
-----    -----    -----                                     
975      148      1                                         
148      002      1                                         
002      155      2                                         
155      156      2                                         
156      157      2                                         
157      051      2                                         
051      978      2
```

```
// Если в цепочке есть разрыв [массив $incorrect]
first    last     num
-----    -----    ----- 
002      148      1
148      975      1
 * * *  Разрыв * * *   
002      155      2
155      156      2
156      157      2
157      051      2
051      978      2
```

Как бы должно получится змейка

Comment: А как понять после разрыва от куда начинать? И почему в примере $correct начинается не с первого элемента массива, а с 3?

Comment: @YaroslavMolchan Если элемент в поле first не встречается в поле last и у него минимальное значение поле num то с него надо начинать. После разрыва также надо определить следующий первый элемент из оставшихся элементов массива которые еще не были распечатаны на экран.

Comment: Понял, так а что не получается?

Comment: @YaroslavMolchan не могу понять как реализовать, знаю что циклами и условиями, но не приходит идеи, уже пару дней думаю и никак не получается

Comment: По идее нужно начать с поиска первого элемента, убираем его с исходного массива и ищем продолжение в том, что осталось, если ничего не находим - то пишем о разрыве, и начинаем с начала, помочь можно когда есть код, а тут не помощь нужна, а сделать всё с нуля.